# Google Cloud SSL connect failure between tomcat and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ssl, tomcat, java

Suddenly started getting this issue.  Both webserver and MySQL server are within same Google Cloud account.  Webserver is running tomcat with jdbc connection coming in as part of context.xml which creates connection pool at startup.  This has been working fine for a few years.   But this weekend it suddenly stopped linking to the database with

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory...

which ultimately is caused by

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol

I've checked the certificates on the MySQL server and they are valid till 2029.   I refreshed them anyway and still get same result.   The only way to get it working again currently is to pass useSSL=false on the connection string which is not ideal.

If I connect from outside of the cloud i.e from my local machine to the MySQL data base I can connect without having to pass the useSSL=false flag.

Anyone any ideas what may have changed?   Do the servers auto update java for example?   If so what can be done to revert?

Thanks in advance